Why my spark sql is not reaching my table in Oracle database?
I am working on a project where I need to update records in an existing table in the Oracle database using PySpark. However, I am facing some challenges with the approach I am using.
Here’s a summary of my problem:
I am trying to use the spark.sql() method to execute an update query on the table, but I find that this method is not suitable for directly updating a table in an external database (like Oracle).
My table already exists, and I cannot use the overwrite mode when writing data back, as this would result in dropping the existing table, which is not allowed in my case.
Using spark.sql(): I attempted to execute an update query directly with spark.sql(), but this results in an error, as spark.sql() is primarily used for working with temporary tables or views registered within Spark.
Writing with write.jdbc: I considered using write.jdbc to insert records, and indeed, using the append mode allows me to insert normally. Here’s a snippet of my code:
if ids_not_in_target.count() > 0:
    ids_not_in_target.write.format("jdbc").mode("append").option("dbtable", target_table).option("url", target_jdbc_url).options(**target_oracle_properties).save()
else:
    update_sql = f"""
    UPDATE target_table
    SET column1 = value1,
        column2 = value2
    WHERE condition
    """
    spark.sql(update_sql)  # This does not work as expected

Error reading data or writing to database:
 [TABLE_OR_VIEW_NOT_FOUND] The table or view `<schema_name>`.`<table_name>` cannot be found. Verify the spelling and correctness of the schema and catalog.
 If you did not qualify the name with a schema, verify the current_schema() output, or qualify the name with the correct schema and catalog.
 To tolerate the error on drop use DROP VIEW IF EXISTS or DROP TABLE IF EXISTS.; line 2 pos 19;
 +- 'UnresolvedRelation [<schema>, <table_name>], [], false

Note: my table exists in the database and I can read and append in the table.
Questions:
What is the best approach to perform an UPDATE operation on an Oracle table using PySpark?
How can I implement an efficient method to update records without using overwrite?
If it is not possible to use spark.sql() or write.jdbc to update directly, is there a way to read the data from the table, apply the updates in a DataFrame, and then write only the changes back to the database?


spark.sql() will execute the sql on current catalog/schema of that SparkSession. You can use the Catalog interface to get all the info on all catalogs/schemas/tables in your current session. You can find that with:

print(spark.catalog.currentCatalog())
print(spark.catalog.currentDatabase())


Use pure python/jdbc to run such SQL. Here is another.
You are misusing PySpark library as a jdbc driver. PySpark is meant for parallel/distributed processing not for running a la carte SQL statements.

